# I have finished a thieves guild quest but can't continue in the campaign

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have finished *"Hard answers"*, but Kaliah doesn't give me the quest *"The pursuit"*, she just walks away. When I try to talk to her, she just says *'hmm..'*.

**How can I continue to the quest *'The pursuit'*?**

Comment: According to [the UESP wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hard_Answers#Bugs), this is a known issue that has to do with having the "Mercer's Plans" item in your inventory. Do you have that in your inventory? If so, the wiki suggests dropping the "Mercer's Plans" item in a safe place/container, talking to Karliah, then retrieving the plans after she has given you the next quest.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give the tablet to Enthir first in order to complete "Hard Answers". After a dialogue, Karliah will tell you to meet here at the Ragged Flagon. Go there by entering the Ratway first (the entrance to the cistern will be blocked). When you reach the Ragged Flaggon, talk to Karliah and then do the rest.